# Change startup Enable / Disable options using .net applications

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, winforms, startup

I have developed an application which will run at system startup.
And it is working fine at system startup,i could see the application in `System Configuration -> Startup`.
All the applications shown at Startup can be enabled / disabled.

> But my question : is it possible to make an application which cannot be disabled
>   at Startup ?
>
> How are Startup properties controlled in registry?

The image shows an application which cannot be disabled at startup.

[image]

On Apply it gets enabled again.

[image]

Comment: No, you can't and you should not do that. If it is ever possible, nobody ever wants to use Windows.

Comment: @kennyzx but some softwares cannot be disabled as i describe in image

Comment: @utility do you mean to say that if you try to uncheck the checkbox for avast that it does not uncheck? Or do you mean that if you uncheck it and click ok and reboot that it will be checked again?

Comment: Maybe Avast used some kind of observation of the registry. The moment an entry in registry changes, avest checks what it was, possible reason: to detect viral applications. And while checking the changes the simply enable there own option again^^

Comment: Of course avast has background running service(s) that keeps monitoring of your applied settings and etc, if it detects that the registry entry is disabled then re-enables it automatically to prevent non-authorized registry modification of a virus attack or for whatever reason, in resuming, that is just a "hidden app" which re-enables the registry entry, there is no automatic feature in Windows to do that you should do it by yourself implementing your logic of a simple registry monitor.

Comment: if you fully disable avast service(s) and main app you will see that the registry entry will not re-enable itself anymore. you could develop a Windows service or a simple winforms with a timer that keep tracking of your registry value to re-enable it in case its disabled. once explained how it works, you still have problems to develop it?.

Answer (score 11):

This question seriously screwed-up my machine.  I'll write it up as a cautionary tale so nobody will do the same stupid thing I did.

I didn't think the OP's claim that these checkboxes could be disabled was very credible.  Never heard of anything like that, surely it would be widely abused if it were possible.  Only way it *could* work is when he's logged-in as a regular user, that's trite, or by removing the modify permission on the registry value for the Admin group.  So I decided to just try it, what could possibly go wrong?

Ran Regedit.exe, picked an entry I didn't care about anyway (Intel shovel-ware).  Edit + Permissions, broke the inheritance chain first so I could control the permissions on each individual value.  Unticked the Full Control option so only Read access remained.

That worked.  Went to restore the permissions.  And discovered something I didn't know before.  These permissions do not apply to the values, they apply to the key.  Obvious only in hind-sight, Regedit however does nothing to make this obvious.  And I didn't just remove the modify right, I also removed the right to change the permissions again.  On *all* the values.

Oh, horror.  I *have* to fix this damage, somehow, it is going to bomb installers in the future.  The only account that still has modify permission is the System account.  I'll have to do something frightful at boot time, maybe write a service.

This is a bad, *bad* idea.  If you have any idea how I can easily repair this then please post a comment.

---

EDIT: I got it back, of sorts, managed to regain control by changing the owner of the key from System to Administrators.

Comment: If you're on Win8 there's a "system reboot" restore option.  If you're on Win7 you might be able to do a system restore.  No idea if either option will work - just an idea.

Comment: Yes but we cannot disable softwares if they are affecting our systems performance through these method know

Comment: @Hans Passant before cracking the unknown keys you could have taken some precautions.

Comment: @HansPassant -   You can run regedit under the system account using [psexec from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) using `psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe`. Doing so should allow you to undo the dirty that you have done

Answer (score 1):

The Simple answer. You cannot.

However, you can hide your startup program from the user (MSConfig) and make it more difficult to disable. Take a look at [activex startup method](http://www.megasecurity.org/Trojaninfo/subseven2.2_startup.html) for more info

Comment: In screen shots it is shown that some softwares like antivirus cannot be disabled.But s/w others can be enabled or disabled

Comment: Im not sure how avast is doing it (probably some hack). But I dont think that windows supports this kind of behavior by default because it would be a security problem.

Comment: was curious to know about that! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create/delete/list startup programs with `wmic` on the command line. For example if you wanted to get a list of all startup programs in html format you could run `wmic startup list /format:htable > startup.html` at the command prompt and then open the resulting file in a web browser. You can also get the table in CSV (`wmic startup list /format:csv > startup.csv`) or a variety of other formats.  
There are also the **Create** and **Delete** options for use. I'm sure you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` in VB.NET or C# with the appropriate arguments to accomplish your goal. Good Luck!

Comment: It was not possible to disable some softwares as shown in the figure

Comment: @utility I do not know of a function that achieves that which you have shown in the figure. I intended to provide something that may provide a similar programmatic functionality.